# GStreamer: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gtk, gstreamer

I am working on a project that I need to display video to a window. So I do some research and find out GStreamer lib is probably a good way to go since I have a GUI written with GTK. However, after 2 hours trying to install and compile GStream on my Mac, I still get:

```
error: gts/gts.h: No such file or directory
```

What I did is install Gstreamer SDK for Mac OS from the official website. Export path:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Version/0.10/Headers:$PATH
```

Compile:

```
gcc test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk-1.0`
```

But I have no luck!. Please help!!!

Comment: Did you mean `gst` not `gts`? PS. Don't compile with `gtk-1.0` libs.

Comment: It is gst. I need to use both gst and gtk lib in my program.

Comment: He meant the error. It looks like you include `gts/gts.h` instead of `gst/gst.h`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant gst not gts. I included gst.h, but the error still there. Btw the compiler also said: 
Package gst-0.10 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gst-0.10.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You can't specify GCC's include path using the PATH variable. Its sole purpose is for the shell (or to be more specific: for the various flavors of [exec()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)) to find executables you want to run.

You might want to modify your gcc command line like that (`gstreamer-0.10` instead of `gst-0.10`):

```
gcc test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gtk-1.0 gstreamer-0.10`
```

If that still doesn't work, look at the output of the pkgconfig command (by running it alone):

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gtk-1.0 gstreamer-0.10
```

That should give you either a list of gcc flags or an error message that should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: that plus remove "gtk-1.0".

Comment: This is what I got after running the command pkg-config command alone:
Package gstreamer-0.10 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gstreamer-0.10.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gstreamer-0.10' found

Comment: @CharlieVictor

ok, as that didn't help, try to find the directory containing gstreamer-0.10.pc (as pkgconfig suggests; use file search or unix `find` to look for it).
Alternatively try installing gstreamer again using http://www.macports.org. And please use copy+paste for your questions. You'd do us (and yourself) a favor.

Comment: @CharlieVictor And: Are you sure you've downloaded gstreamer-0.10 or the new stable 1.0?

Comment: I download it from here:
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Mac+OS+X

The library folder says it is v0.10